# call a function in Python syntax

Tags: python, syntax

Hey im writing a small program in python 2.6 and i have defined 
2 helper functions which does almost all i want, for instance

```
def helper1:
    ...


def helper2:
    ...
```

Now my problem is that i want to make a new function that gather the two functions in one function so i dont have to write (in shell):

```
list(helper1(helper2(argument1,argument2)))
```

but instead just

```
function(argument1,argument2)
```

Is there any short way around that? Im all new to python, or do you need more code-sample to be able to answer?

Thanx in advance for any hints or help

Answer (score 8):

```
def function(arg1, arg2):
    return list(helper1(helper2(arg1, arg2)))
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
function = lambda x, y: list(helper1(helper2(x, y)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of the higher order function `compose`. It's handy to have laying around

```
def compose(*functions):
    """ Returns the composition of functions"""
    functions = reversed(functions)
    def composition(*args, **kwargs):
        func_iter = iter(functions)
        ret = next(func_iter)(*args, **kwargs)
        for f in func_iter:
            ret = f(ret)
        return ret
    return composition
```

You can now write your function as

```
function1 = compose(list, helper1, helper2)
function2 = compose(tuple, helper3, helper4)
function42 = compose(set, helper4, helper2)
```

etc.